# Rails NoMethodError: private method on private method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to use the Rails console to iterate through all `Ad` models. I want each ad to perform a private method called `extract_targets`:

```
Ad.all.each do |ad|
  ad.extract_targets
end
```

Though when I get the following error while looping:

```
NoMethodError: private method `extract_targets' called for #<Ad:0x000000071123b0>
```

It's a private method but I'm calling it from each of the ads so I don't know why it raises an exception?

```
  private

  def extract_targets
    normal_name = campaign.name.sub(/^www\./, '')
    links = page.css('a').map { |link| URI(link['href']) }.select {|link|     link.host.sub(/^www\./, '').end_with? normal_name }
    location = links.first.path
    location = '/' if location.empty?
    location.normalize_path!
    update_column :target_id, campaign.targets.find_or_create_by(location: location).id
  end
```

Comment: Private method can be called only from inside the class

Comment: @DeepakMahakale: and even then, not always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call private methods with explicit receiver. So either make it public, or use `send`, or call *another* method on `Ad` that will call this one.

Comment: What about protected?

Comment: Same thing, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In console, you can use the send method to check private methods out. So `ad.send(:extract_targets)` should work.

Comment: In this case, what's the point of having it private? Might as well make it public.

Comment: He's just testing it in console. It won't be part of the actual app. A user can't call .send on anything. But if you need to test/poke at something in the console that is private (for the rest of the word), .send is quite handy.

Comment: Well, to me it looks very much like a part of an actual app.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by writing a class method on your model.

**ad.rb**

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def self.extract_all_targets
    all.each do |ad|
      ad.extract_targets
    end
  end

  private

  def extract_targets
    ...
  end
end
```

then use it in your console:

```
Ad.extract_all_targets
```

Comment: Nope, this  code wouldn't work, for exactly the same reason.